# How to convert nested tags in dynamic XML into a for loop?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jsoup

I want to convert dynamic xml file into a specific file format. i could able to parse the xml using jsoup parser but the problem is I want to parse the nested tags and put it into a for-loop.Is there any way to do it. Attaching the sample below for reference

Input XML(sample)

```
                         <lineComponents>
                        <invoiceComponents>
                            <invoiceComponent>
                                <type></type>
                                <name></name>
                                <amount>16.00</amount>
                                <taxPercentage>0.00</taxPercentage>
                                <taxAmount>0E-8</taxAmount>
                            </invoiceComponent>
                        </invoiceComponents>
                        <acctComponents>
                            <acctComponent>
                                <componentCode>BASE</componentCode>
                                <glAccountNr></glAccountNr>
                                <baseAmount>10.00000</baseAmount>
                                <taxRate>0.00</taxRate>
                                <taxAmount>0.00000</taxAmount>
                                <totalAmount>10.00000</totalAmount>
                                <isVAT>No</isVAT>
                            </acctComponent>
                            <acctComponent>
                                <componentCode></componentCode>
                                <glAccountNr></glAccountNr>
                                <baseAmount>3.00000</baseAmount>
                                <taxRate>0.00</taxRate>
                                <taxAmount>0.00000</taxAmount>
                                <totalAmount>3.00000</totalAmount>
                                <isVAT>No</isVAT>
                            </acctComponent>
                            <acctComponent>
                                <componentCode>DISC</componentCode>
                                <glAccountNr></glAccountNr>
                                <baseAmount>-2.00000</baseAmount>
                                <taxRate>0.00</taxRate>
                                <taxAmount>0.00000</taxAmount>
                                <totalAmount>-2.00000</totalAmount>
                                <isVAT>No</isVAT>
                            </acctComponent>
                            <acctComponent>
                                <componentCode>ARPIT</componentCode>
                                <glAccountNr></glAccountNr>
                                <baseAmount>5.00000</baseAmount>
                                <taxRate>0.00</taxRate>
                                <taxAmount>0.00000</taxAmount>
                                <totalAmount>5.00000</totalAmount>
                                <isVAT>No</isVAT>
                            </acctComponent>
                        </acctComponents>
                    </lineComponents>
```

Expected output:

```
 for(OrderItem invoiceLineItem: orderLineWrp.invoiceLineItems){
            Dom.XMLNode invoiceComponentNode = invoiceComponentsNode.addChildElement(EP_OrderConstant.invoiceComponent,null,null);
            invoiceComponentNode.addChildElement(EP_OrderConstant.seqId,null,null).addTextNode(getValueforNode(invoiceLineItem.EP_SeqId__c));
            invoiceComponentNode.addChildElement(EP_OrderConstant.TYPE,null,null).addTextNode(getValueforNode(invoiceLineItem.EP_ChargeType__c));
            invoiceComponentNode.addChildElement(EP_OrderConstant.name,null,null).addTextNode(getValueforNode(invoiceLineItem.EP_Invoice_Name__c));
            invoiceComponentNode.addChildElement(EP_OrderConstant.amount,null,null).addTextNode(getValueforNode(invoiceLineItem.UnitPrice)); //Value for amount
            invoiceComponentNode.addChildElement(EP_OrderConstant.taxPercentage,null,null).addTextNode(getValueforNode(invoiceLineItem.EP_Tax_Percentage__c)); //Value for taxPercentage
            invoiceComponentNode.addChildElement(EP_OrderConstant.taxAmount,null,null).addTextNode(getValueforNode(invoiceLineItem.EP_Tax_Amount_XML__c)); //Value for taxAmount
        }
```

This Xml file is dynamic. Is there any way to handle dynamic XML file into a specific format like above?

Comment: Tell me more about what you want to achieve. Are you sure you pasted correct "expected output"?

Answer (score -1):

Jsoup is rather for HTML parsing.

If you have XSD/DTD to your XML, you should use [JAXB-generated classes](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-generate-classes-xsd/) and an [unmarshaller](https://dzone.com/articles/using-jaxb-for-xml-with-java) to read it.

Otherwise you can use [JAXP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html) (DOMParser, if the file is small, and [XPath](https://www.journaldev.com/1194/java-xpath-example-tutorial), or event based [SAXParser](https://www.admfactory.com/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-using-sax-parser/)(however this is not so easy to use) for really large XML files).

Comment: Jsoup easily handles XML. It even has another parser type for that `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xmlString, "", Parser.xmlParser());`

Comment: I have not stated that it can not be used for that, but IMHO there are better tools to do that.